# several images onclick maintain other images

Tags: html, css, image

So I am trying to find out a way to view images without hiding the rest when clicked on

for instance

```
  <a href ="someimage.jpg"><img src="someimage.jpg"/></a>
  <a href ="someimage2.jpg"><img src="someimage2.jpg"/></a>
  <a href ="someimage3.jpg"><img src="someimage3.jpg"/></a>
  <a href ="someimage4.jpg"><img src="someimage4.jpg"/></a>
```

for instance when i click on the first image it opens up in a new window and thats it
i´d like to be able to scroll through these images. i´d like to be able to go to the next image by clicking "next" for instance or something like that!

Comment: Go back through and accept answers to your previous questions. Some of them are quite good and evidently took a lot of thought.

Answer (score 0):

Calling an image in the browser directly will return that file, not an html page with the file embedded. In your case you will have to write a page that handles this functionality for you.

You don't mention whether or not javascript / jquery is an option for you, but it would definitely be the easiest solution in my opinion.

Look into something like a [jquery carousel](http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-carousel.html) to handle a basic slideshow.

And if this is not the answer you were looking for, then I'm afraid the solution for you - fitting your limits of html, css and image - is to make individual html pages for each image and hard code the next and previous links... each and every one... the good ol fashioned way.

```
... headers
<body>
    <img src="someimage.jpg" alt=""><br>
    <a href="anotherimage.html">Previous</a> | <a href="someimage2.html">Next</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://fancybox.net/ Has a great javascript type plugin for having the image show up in a type of lightbox. Otherwise seach for "jquery image zoom plugin". That should give you some good plugins *if* javascript will work for you.